# Is it possible to create a local SRV record in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, internal-dns, srv-record

Is there something like `/etc/hosts` file for `SRV` records? I would like my Alpine Linux server to find the value of `_xmpp-server._tcp` `SRV` record locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux does not have a built in method for that, you should look into `dnsmasq` and setup a lightweight DNS resolver, first install it

```
apk add dnsmasq
```

then we create a configuration file for example here `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

put this inside

```
# Use the following DNS servers as the upstream servers
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

# Define your local SRV record
srv-host=_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com,server.example.com,5269,0,5

# Replace "example.com" with your domain and "server.example.com" with your server's hostname
```

then we start it

```
rc-service dnsmasq start
rc-update add dnsmasq
```

and now you can configure your server to use our DNS resolver, add this at the top of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Note that on modern distros, `/etc/resolv.conf` is often managed by NetworkManager or systemd which means changes will be overwritten on the next reboot/network change.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Though you can generally override that in turn (or just make your changes and mark the file immutable, though things may complain vociferously about this in your log files).

Comment: @Ginnungagap: You could...configure the NetworkManager or systemd-networkd connection profiles to use 127.0.0.1 as the DNS server?

Comment: Yes I was just warning against editing `/etc/resolv.conf` directly. I'm not saying it's unfeasible, just that the current will likely work temporarily only.